# Trying to run javaFX on java sdk 15 with the module from javaFX 15 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

This is the error, however it only occurs when using the Button class.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x5b3ec5dc) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x5b3ec5dc
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at Main.start(Main.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application Main
```

This is the code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click Me");
        stage.setTitle("First JavaFX GUI");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

When I remove the Button, it runs fine and shows the window, however when using Button it throws that error. How can I solve this. I am currently in a Mac, using IntelliJ. JDK 15 with JavaFX 15.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, I think something is going on with your `module-info.java` file. Make sure it has something like `requires javafx.controls;
    exports com.org.yourprojectname;`

Comment: Where would you add this. In main?

Comment: You should have a file called `module-info.java`. You should add it there.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/intellij/modular/ide/idea01.png

Comment: Follow [these](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ you should add this to the VM options under the Run Configurations.
--module-path ***PathToJavaFX*** --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml.

the ***PathToJavaFx*** should be the /lib folder.

Comment: I solved it this way, but when doing this was unable to compile a java application via IntelliJ, it kept saying that it couldn't find main. So I had to switch to java 8 to compile with the JavaFX built in process in IntelliJ, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very challenging time working with JavaFX and modules. So far I've worked out how to incorporate Maven and SQL, but if I add in a module-info file, it fails.

Basically, the issue that I ran into (which produced the same result that you're having) was solved by me either:  removing module-info and removing Maven, but having OpenJFX as a library for the project, or removing the library & module-info, but acquiring OpenJFX via Maven.

The issue was doubling up on JavaFX locations/references and the module-info file mucking up the works.

Thought it might be useful to share what's been working for me.  Good luck!